# Scale animation using jQuery fadeOut()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, fadeout

I was searching a while but didn't found a post about this: I'm using `jQuery` `fadeOut()` to `animate` an element.

I want to fade out the element with a `scale` of `1.75` (175%) by using jQuery's `fadeOut()` function. At the moment it's a common fade out animation, but I'd like that the fade out animation scales out (element inflates).

I've made an example (the lightblue element) with a CSS animation using `keyframes`. I would like to solve the animation with `fadeOut()` (maybe you have to scroll down the snippet to see the example), is this possible? I hope this is clear enough.

```js
$('.hide').click(function() {
  $('.animate').fadeOut(500);
});

$('.show').click(function() {
  $('.animate').fadeIn(500);
});
```

```css
.animate {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.animate--css {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.animate--css {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  animation: zoomOut 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes zoomOut {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.75);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="hide">Fade out</button>
<button class="show">Fade in</button>
<div class="animate"></div>
<div class="animate--css"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `start` to apply a CSS before fading the element:

```js
$('.hide').click(function() {
  $('.animate').fadeOut({'start':function() {$(this).css('transform','scale(1.75)') },'duration':500});
});

$('.show').click(function() {
  $('.animate').fadeIn({'start':function() {$(this).css('transform','scale(1)') },'duration':500});
});
```

```css
.animate {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightcoral;
  margin-top: 20px;
  transition:0.5s all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="hide">Fade out</button>
<button class="show">Fade in</button>
<div class="animate"></div>
```